# Combine Multiple Data Columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe -

```
df = 
    1.0         2.0         3.0             4.0         5.0
(1083, 596)                             (1050, 164)   (1050, 164)   
(1081, 595)                             (1050, 164)   (1080, 162)
(1081, 594)                             (1049, 163)   (1070, 164)
(1082, 593) 
            (1050, 164)     
            (1050, 164)     
            (1049, 163)     
            (1049, 163)     

                        (1052, 463)
                        (1051, 468)
                        (1054, 465)
                        (1057, 463)
```

I need a completely new dataframe, `df2`, with 3 columns: 1.0, 2.0 (combines 2.0 and 4.0) and 3.0 (combines 3.0 and 5.0).

The result will be -

```
df2 = 
    1.0         2.0         3.0     
(1083, 596) (1050, 164)   (1050, 164)   
(1081, 595) (1050, 164)   (1080, 162)
(1081, 594) (1049, 163)   (1070, 164)
(1082, 593) 
            (1050, 164)     
            (1050, 164)     
            (1049, 163)     
            (1049, 163)     

                        (1052, 463)
                        (1051, 468)
                        (1054, 465)
                        (1057, 463)
```

You can expect that there will be no overlapping values in the merged columns; if one column has valid value in a row then others will have NaN value.

I tried -

```
df.fillna(0)
df2['2.0']=df['2.0']+df['4.0']
```

and it does not work as intended. Is there any simple and efficient method of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.where()` and `DataFrame.isnull()` to mix the values the way you are trying to:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df["1.0"], columns=["1.0"])
df2["2.0"] = df["2.0"].where(~df2["2.0"].isnull(), df2["4.0"])
df2["3.0"] = df["3.0"].where(~df2["3.0"].isnull(), df2["5.0"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just basically copying and pasting. I think this works.

```
# copy values over to your other columns
# note: [0:3,'2.0'] gets the first 4 rows (index 0 to 3) of column '2.0'
# then you set it equal to the first 4 rows of column '4.0'

df.loc[0:3,'2.0'] = df.loc[0:3,'4.0'] 
df.loc[0:3,'3.0'] = df.loc[0:3,'5.0'] 


# just get the three columns you need


df2 = df[['1.0','2.0','3.0']]


           1.0          2.0          3.0
0   (1083, 596)  (1050, 164)  (1050, 164)
1   (1081, 595)  (1050, 164)  (1080, 162)
2   (1081, 594)  (1049, 163)  (1070, 164)
3   (1082, 593)          NaN          NaN
4           NaN  (1050, 164)          NaN
5           NaN  (1050, 164)          NaN
6           NaN  (1049, 163)          NaN
7           NaN  (1049, 163)          NaN
8           NaN          NaN          NaN
9           NaN          NaN  (1052, 463)
10          NaN          NaN  (1051, 468)
11          NaN          NaN  (1054, 465)
12          NaN          NaN  (1057, 463)
```

If your column names are actually floats, remove the quotation marks from these sections: `df.loc[0:3,'2.0']` e.g. change to `df.loc[0:3,2.0]` like:

```
df.loc[0:3,2.0] = df.loc[0:3,4.0] 
df.loc[0:3,3.0] = df.loc[0:3,5.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume whitespaces in `df` are `NaN`s. You only need shift columns `'2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0'` left 2 positions and do `combine_first` with `df`. Finally, pick first 3 columns by using `iloc`

```
df2 = df.combine_first(df.drop('1.0',1).shift(-2, axis=1)).iloc[:,:3]

Out[297]:
           1.0         2.0         3.0
0   (1083, 596)  (1050, 164)  (1050, 164)
1   (1081, 595)  (1050, 164)  (1080, 162)
2   (1081, 594)  (1049, 163)  (1070, 164)
3   (1082, 593)         NaN         NaN
4          NaN  (1050, 164)         NaN
5          NaN  (1050, 164)         NaN
6          NaN  (1049, 163)         NaN
7          NaN  (1049, 163)         NaN
8          NaN         NaN  (1052, 463)
9          NaN         NaN  (1051, 468)
10         NaN         NaN  (1054, 465)
11         NaN         NaN  (1057, 463)
```